# Grafana Loki Timestamp, LogQL Query issues

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki, promtail

I’m new to my PLG, and facing some issues with the monitoring, please suggest on this.

my log format is like below - which has utc time as timestamp

time duration ip username method message

ex: 2021-09-27T06:39:42.1756Z 200 00:00.001 1.1.17.110 testuser GET this is log message

and below is the promtail configuration

[promtailconfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojDtv.png)

Issues:

1. The timestamp showing in grafana dashboard is time in which the logs have added to Loki.
2. old logs are not processing, only new ones are getting displayed in grafana.
3. how to calculate (LogQL query) the average duration of all calls in each server (host label) ?

thanks in advance.